# What is a good CPAN parser for HTML MS Excel files?

Tags: perl, parsing, html-parsing, excel

I know that regular (binary) Excel files can be processed via `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`.

However, I have a file that is HTML formatted:

```
<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=windows-1252">
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<xml>
<x:ExcelWorkbook>
<x:ExcelWorksheets>
<x:ExcelWorksheet>
<x:Name>Holdings</x:Name>
<x:WorksheetOptions>
```

Short of manually parsing it as a generic HTML file (e.g. TreeBuilder etc..), is there a CPAN module that would parse and let me access such a file as a spreadsheet, similar to  `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`?

Here's where the module doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $file     = 'file1.xls';
my $workbook;
eval {$workbook   = $parser->Parse($file);}; 
#($Workbook returned here is ‘undef’)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use an XPath parser to extract what I need from files like this, iterating on `./Cell/Data` nodes inside of the `//Row` nodes, but that's not using the same interface as `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`.

I also find that you need to do some source filtering before you can use the XML parser. At a minimum you have to run

```
s/<xml version>/<!-- xml version -->/;
s/&/&amp;/g
```

on the input.

---

Here's a concise but complete solution, extracting a file like this to a 2-D array:

```
use XML::XPath;
open F, '<', $dirty_file_name;
open G, '>', $clean_file_name;
while(<F>) { 
    s/<xml version>/<!-- xml version -->/;
    s/&/&amp;/g;
    print G
}
close G;
close F;

@table = map { [ map { $_->string_value } $_->find('./Cell/Data')->get_nodelist ]
  } XML::XPath->new( filename => $clean_file_name )->find('//Row')->get_nodelist;
```

Comment: No purpose built CPAN module? I'm shocked!

Comment: Here's your bug chance.  Bundle @mob's solution with some additional helper methods and you've a winner.